# Is QA manual testing dead?

Tags: automated-tests

Can I automate all type of tests (unit test, ... etc) so that I don't need QA team to do manual tesing? And if no, Why?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663231/can-automated-testing-completely-replace-the-need-for-manual-testing

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would sum it up thusly:

- Automated tests are for finding the problems that you **know about** (incorrect code).
- Manual tests are for finding the problems that you **don't know about** (incorrect design/specs).

If you use manual tests to find problems with the code, that is inefficient.  If you use automated tests to find problems with the design, that is inexcusable.

Answer (score 10):

Black box testing will never go away as long as human beings are using your product.  There is no substitute for the human ability to identify "something weird going on".

Comment: +1  This is really the unfortunately truth...

Comment: I don't know if it's unfortunate; there's nothing better than having good QA people.

Answer (score 9):

No.

Your QA can be a smaller team, and their purpose becomes finding unexpected things.  They get to play with the system in ways that a user might.  In ways that programmers didn't expect.

Once they find something, you write an automated test so they don't need to repeat it.  But you still need them to find those cases.

Not to mention, they'll find things like typos, usability issues with the UI, hard to read colour combinations, etc

Answer (score 5):

Automated testing is only as good as the tests.  Theoretically, if you could write a test for every potential interaction the user will make with your system, manual testing would be obsolete.  However, that's not practical, at all.

Good testing will reduce the amount of manual testing required by a QA team, but not eliminate it.  In addition, good automation tests can help prevent having to retest problems manually, since once a problem is discovered, a good test can be developed to automatically handle *that specific scenario* in the future.

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons for the Vista experience was supposedly that MSFT had cut back on 'mere human' testers in favor of tester-programmers who wrote scripts.

Of course the scripts didn't notice things like the wide range of different themes as you went deeper into the control panel, or the copy estimate dialogs or other 'minor' gui features that made the whole product look crap

Answer (score 3):

Manual QA, more commonly known as Blackbox QA, is far from dead.

It's true that unit tests and general automated tests can cover at least 90% of code-path testing. What many don't realize is that the last manual 10% can be the some of the most important work a software and hardware organization can do.

Let's take the user interface, for example. A unit test can tell you that a check box is placed in the right location, and turns on and off as expected. What the test can't tell you is that it's horribly bitmapped and looks terrible with the hideous purple and yellow color scheme in the application.

The most important reason for Blackbox QA is that you end up with strong customer advocate inside your organization. Many of these QA people (myself included), have more of a creative background than a programming background. While some may think of this as a failing, these are the people who don't care about how the code works - they care about how the product works. They spend time thinking like a customer, rather than a developer; "Oh, my almost dead iPod is finished syncing, that means I can close my laptop and just let it charge. Yup, and then I'll just pull it out when my machine is asleep (even though I was playing music from it on my computer) and everything will be fine."

Developers and testers know how a product is supposed to work, and all exercise a product to specification. It's a good tester's job to use the product in a careless way, to make sure that bad stuff doesn't happen. Yank a USB drive from a computer while you're copying data, are you crazy?!? Sure, that's a really stupid idea. But people do it all the time. And a good QA person will do just that, to make sure that pulling a hard drive doesn't take a whole system down. Or turning off WiFi when downloading a movie, or syncing music while purchasing new content and then changing your account password and email address at the same time. Or installing an OS on an MP3 player and trying to boot from it, then pulling the player from the system while it's booted from the device (Yup, I did that, and found a really good bug from it).

Joel on Software says "Why QA" much more eloquently than I do - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/01/26.html

Answer (score 2):

No!

Not everything can be tested by automated testing. Please do not suggest that! User interface aesthetics is something that your QA team should be helping you fix, which automated testing cannot. Just to name one.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. Automated tests are code. They can have bugs of their own that will mask bugs in the AUT. Also no automated test is capable of asking, "What if I do this?", or capable making an educated guess about where faults are most likely to occur. Automated exploratory testing does not exist.

On the mechanical side of things, it's also generally inefficient to write an automated test that will only be run once. If doing it manually takes less time than developing the test, it's a waste to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring manual testing will cause you to miss important bugs that automation simply can not catch. Real world testing requires the right mix of manual and automated testing.

User experience and interface issues can only be identified with manual testing.

Automation is great for regressions testing because it is being done on a stable environment where the user experience has already been vetted.

Automation is also great for removing a lot of the tedious tasks for testers so they can focus efforts on new features or areas where UI bugs are more likely.

Answer (score 1):

[On my experience in using both Manual & Automation]

**Manual Testing:** This is actual testing where you can try different scenarios based on current situation, say for example when the network is down how your application behaves, where you can disconnect and connect the network and check for results. This helps to deal with Functional bugs and also UI bugs.

**Automation Testing:** Where the continues script executed regularly, where these scripts also need to be updated similar to the application update also there is a chance to provide wrong results if there is a delay in page loading or network response or slowness.

Both has its own pros and cons, however, Automation cannot replace the manual testing for a larger logical application.
User interaction scenarios like video conference are not advisable for automation. 
Automation scripts are itself the code, which can also have bugs, where it can produce wrong results sometimes.
Automation may suit for some application where the contents remain same for longer days and also functionality and values are static mostly.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can I automate all type of tests (unit test, ... etc) so that I don't need QA team to do manual tesing?*

No

> *And if no, Why?*

Not all the technologies/test are suitable for automation.

Aside from that, if the automatic test code is written by the same individual who wrote the code to be test, then is is possible that the test is missing some important ( yet, not detected by the original developer ) aspect to be validated.

Comment: Nearly all test can be automated. There are test for CSS, test mimicking users, load test and everything else. The few things that might not be easily testable are exploratory test and drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

In the start of new project We get SRS or Prototypes,So once only QA understand the Workflow of the application he can go for automation for the application.Automation does not come into play if manual testing is not done .But manual testing is possible always.

Answer (score 0):

automated you can do but don't check the design so if u check design or ui u can do manual testing

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can't.
2. Because, automating a test just confirm that a test is covered on a fixed condition. But there can multiple scenario which can be find out by only manual test. Also, based on requirements, existing product can be changes/updated/can have newly added feature. So before automating tests for them, you must have to run manual tests to be sure that every test conditions are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

At the end all test cases are executed by a human being. Even though the whole system is automated there are times that you will have to do a little bit of manual testing here and there.

Where automated testing helps you to find out bugs with the functionalities you're already aware of and manual testing helps you to find out bugs that you may have missed automating.

Answer (score -1):

No

Bec automation is mainly used for regression testing not for all test cases.

Manual testing is evergreen.

adhoc testing and exploratory testing should be done with manual only